# The $j$-invariant of my donut

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

I have a donut. Its boundary is a two-dimensional surface embedded in three-dimensional space, and surely is homeomorphic to a torus. If we fix a Riemannian metric on the space, it induces a two-dimensional [Riemannian metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) on the donut. Forgetting the scaling, we get a [conformal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry#Conformal_manifolds) on the surface. If we fix an orientation, this defines a [complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Definitions).

[Complex surfaces homeomorphic to a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) are classified by their [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Definition). Thus, I would like to calculate the [$j$-invariant](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gm/teaching/MATH32062/j-inv.pdf) of my donut. There are several variants of this question:

1. Suppose my donut is modeled in cylindrical coordinates $(r,z,\theta)$ by the equation $(r-1)^2 + z^2=\rho^2$. What is the $j$-invariant as a function of $\rho$?
2. Find an actual, real donut, and approximate it by a surface of this form. Estimate $\rho$ and thereby estimate its $j$-invariant.
3. Determine how your donut differs from this model, and estimate in which direction that might change its $j$-invariant. Or solve a different model that better fits your donut.

I would be happy to see progress on any of these vitally important problems, which you will no doubt agree have many fruitful applications to mathematics and our daily life.

Comment: I tried 2, but ended up eating the doughnut!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is woke af for eating the 

Comment: If your donut is a jelly donut then it will not be homeomorphic to a torus and will thus not be able to be classified by a j-invariant. You will have to use a related invariant called a jelly-invariant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $\rho\in (0,1)$, write $D_{\rho}$ for your donut $(r-1)^2 + z^2 = \rho^2$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define 
$$
q_\rho(x):=2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tan\left(\frac{x\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{2\rho}\right)-\rho.
$$
We define a parametrization of $D_\rho$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{\rho}:\mathbb{C}&\to D_{\rho}\\
x+iy&\mapsto \left(1+\rho\frac{2 q_\rho(x)}{1+q_\rho(x)^2},\rho\frac{1-q_\rho(x)^2}{1+q_\rho(x)^2},y\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Here the image is written in $(r,z,\theta)$ coordinates. Note that this function is defined even where $q_\rho(y)$ has poles. It is straightforward but tedious to verify that $f_\rho$ is conformal. If we write $r(x)$, $z(x)$ for the $r$- and $z$-coordinates, this amounts to the identity
$$
r'(x)^2+z'(x)^2=r(x)^2.
$$
I used a CAS to find the formula for $f_\rho$.

From the formula, we see that $f_{\rho}$ is doubly periodic, with minimal periods $2\pi i$ and $2\pi\rho/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$. Thus $D_\rho$ is conformally equivalent to the torus
$$
\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\mathbb{Z}+i\frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\rho}\mathbb{Z}}.
$$
Write $j(\tau)$ for the $j$-function, which takes $\tau$ in the upper half plane to the $j$-invariant of $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z})$. The $j$-invariant of $D_{\rho}$ is then
$$
j\left(i\frac{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\rho}\right).
$$

I don't have a donut in front of me, but the internet suggests that a Krispy Kream original glazed has outter diameter $3.5''$ and width from edge to hole $1.4''$. Scaling, this gives the value $\rho=\frac{2}{3}$. Sage then gives the estimate
$$
j\approx 2060.94946856905.
$$